# How to find List of subMap with nested subMap

Tags: groovy

I have a `List` of `Map` with nested `Map` as well as below :-

```
def list = [
            [
                "description": "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it.",
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Open",
                "statusCategory": [
                    "colorName": "blue-gray",
                    "id": 2,
                    "key": "new",
                    "name": "To Do",
                ]
            ],
            [
                "description": "This issue is being actively worked on at the moment by the assignee.",
                "id": "3",
                "name": "In Progress",
                "statusCategory": [
                    "colorName": "yellow",
                    "id": 4,
                    "key": "indeterminate",
                    "name": "In Progress",
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

I have a task to get `List` of `subMap` with nested `subMap`. I'm doing some thing like as below :-

```
def getSubMap = { lst ->
            lst.findResults { it.subMap(["id", "name", "statusCategory"])}
}

println getSubMap(list)
```

But its give me output as below :-

```
[
  [
    "id":1, 
    "name":"Open", 
    "statusCategory":[
        "colorName":"blue-gray", 
        "id":2, 
        "key":"new", 
        "name":"To Do"
    ]
  ], 
  [
    "id":"3", 
    "name":"In Progress", 
    "statusCategory":[
       "colorName":"yellow", 
       "id":"4", 
       "key":"indeterminate", 
       "name":"In Progress"
   ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see I'm unable to get `subMap` of `statusCategory` key `Map`. Actually I want to get further `subMap` for nested `Maps` something like as below :-

```
[
  [
    "id":1, 
    "name":"Open", 
    "statusCategory":[
        "id":"2", 
        "name":"To Do"
    ]
  ], 
  [
    "id":"3", 
    "name":"In Progress", 
    "statusCategory":[
       "id":"4", 
       "name":"In Progress"
   ]
  ]
]
```

To achieve this I'm trying as below :-

```
def getSubMap = { lst ->
            lst.findResults { it.subMap(["id", "name", "statusCategory":["id","name"]])}
}

def modifiedList = getSubMap(list)
```

But it throws me `Excpetion`. And If I'm doing as below :-

```
def getSubMap = { lst ->
        lst.findResults { it.subMap(["id", "name", "statusCategory"]).statusCategory.subMap(["id","name"])}
}

println getSubMap(list)
```

It gives only nested `subMap` as :-

```
 [["id":"2", "name":"To Do"], ["id":"4", "name":"In Progress"]]
```

could anyone suggest me how to recurselvely find `List` of `subMap` with nested `subMap` if exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Map` nesting is arbitrary, then you might want to consider something like this:

```
def nestedSubMap
nestedSubMap = { Map map, List keys ->
    map.subMap(keys) + map.findAll { k, v -> v instanceof Map }.collectEntries { k, v -> [(k):nestedSubMap(v, keys)] }
}
```

Given your input and this closure, the following script:

```
def result = list.collect { nestedSubMap(it, ["id", "name"]) }
println '['
result.each { print it; println ',' }
println ']'
```

Produces this output:

```
[
[id:1, name:Open, statusCategory:[id:2, name:To Do]],
[id:3, name:In Progress, statusCategory:[id:4, name:In Progress]],
]
```

Comment: Your answer helpful but key is not always constant for map as well as nested map, thanks..:)

Comment: Actually my solution is not that limited. It works with any set of subMap keys, but the expectation is that whatever keys are specified will be valid for all the nested maps. I will correct the text to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Given the original `list`, consider this:

```
def resultList = list.collect { 
    def fields = ["id", "name"]
    def m = it.subMap(fields)
    m["statusCategory"] = it["statusCategory"].subMap(fields)
    return m
}
```

which supports these assertions:

```
assert 1 == resultList[0]["id"] as int
assert "Open" == resultList[0]["name"]
assert 2 == resultList[0]["statusCategory"]["id"] as int
assert "To Do" == resultList[0]["statusCategory"]["name"]

assert 3 == resultList[1]["id"] as int
assert "In Progress" == resultList[1]["name"]
assert 4 == resultList[1]["statusCategory"]["id"] as int
assert "In Progress" == resultList[1]["statusCategory"]["name"]
```